# Sequence Number in testing Spring application with JUnit (Hibernating, Spring MVC)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, junit4

I am testing DAO in Spring Application.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class CommentDAOImplTest { @Autowired //testing mehods here}
```

The tests are running good. Iam able to add an comment and I also have a defaultRollback property set. So, the added comment will be deleted automatically. happy!..Now the problem is with the sequence number for mcomment. Can I, in any way rollback the seq number? any suggestins on that. I dont want to mess up the sequrnce number. Business requires comment Id to be showed. (I still dont know why).

I know in memory db is an option....but I am guessing defaultRollback purpose is to eliminate in memory db testing and mocking. (Just my opinion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a test database which you wipe before you start the tests.

Do not run tests in the production database (might accidentally insert test data into production) and never copy production into test database (this would be a strong indication that you have no idea what you're testing and that testing is an afterthought at best).

Comment: So, there is no solution for sequence number rollback. I would stick with HSQL db.

Comment: HSQL or H2 is a good basis for unit tests. DBs can't roll back sequences because they might have been used in two transactions. What do you expect to happen when two transactions increased the sequence and then the first one is rolled back?

Comment: That said, sequences are probably a bad choice for consecutive numbers in comments for the reason I just mentioned plus they make tests brittle. If you have problems with changing IDs in tests, then exclude the ID part from asserts or get the ID before the assert and put it into the expected pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with HSQL DB there is no solution, but you can use `@DirtiesContext` spring's annotation before each `@Test` method. For example:

```
@Test
@DirtiesContext
public final void foo() {
    //Get the first sequence value = 0
    //Next value = 1
}

@Test
@DirtiesContext
public final void foo2() {
    //Gets 0, not 2
    //Next value = 1
}
```

@DirtiesContext. Use this annotation if a test has modified the context — for example, by modifying the state of a singleton bean, modifying the state of an embedded database, etc. Subsequent tests that request the same context will be supplied a new context.

Basically you are initializing a new spring context before each method, but at least you can test your sequence or whatever you are trying to test.